# AngularJS: avoid url encoding with $location

Tags: angularjs

I notice that when I passed a parameter that is an array to $location.search(), it was encoded as in the following example

$location.path('/somePath').search('ids[]=', [1, 2, 3]);

becomes

/somePath?ds%5B%5D=1&ds%5B%5D=2&ds%5B%5D=3

Is there a way to avoid the url encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse the late reply, but I struck a similar predicament myself and thought I'd offer advice.

In short, if you intend on using `$location.search` you cannot avoid the URL being encoded.

If you take a look at the Angular source, [`location.js`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js) specifically, you'll notice that the functions return composed URLs (i.e. `LocationHtml5Url`) all rely on another function call named `toKeyValue`, which will encode all key-value pairs whenever they are set.

Furthermore, in the example use case you've provided, you don't need the equals inside your key. When `$location.search` is called with two parameters, they are treated as a key-value pair by Angular.

If you need to make use of the location URL after it has been encoded, you could always call [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

Answer (score 1):

Some years late, but I have found a way to bypass the URI encode made by the $location service: just rewrite the `window.encodeURIComponent`

```
var original = window.encodeURIComponent;
window.encodeURIComponent = function (str) {
   return decodeURI(str);
};
$location.url('/somePath?ids=[1,2,3]');
window.encodeURIComponent = original;
```

It is not the best solution, but it works as intended.