# Prevent url encoding in AngularJS route

Tags: angularjs

Currently, when I pass my query string into the search() method of $location, my query string is uri encoded

Example

```
$location.path('/some_path').search({'ids[]': 1})
```

becomes

```
http://some_url/some_path?ids%5B%5D=1
```

I wonder if there's a way to get around this?

Comment: I want to have the param name semantically defined instead of using something like a comma separated list.

Comment: There is a way around this, but the more important question is, should you?  Special characters should be encoded in a URL.  If you don't want to show it's 'ugliness' use a post instead of a get.

Comment: What is your reason for this? Even if you come up with one good one, there's a million others that oppose it. Regardless of how AngularJS encodes the URL, when `$location.search()` is called it un-encodes the URL back into your original object. At this point, the only reason for doing what you're trying to do is to make the URL look prettier in the browser.

Comment: @Mike can you name few of the million reasons, please? :)

Comment: I am re-writing frontend part of a PHP app into Angular and need to keep the new URLs same. The URL uses "/" and ";" as separators for some parameters.

Comment: @J_A_X The URL is updated because we want users to be able to copy/paste or bookmark the URL. POST cannot be used in this case.

Comment: @PetrPeller You're using a roundabout way of doing that then.  Why are you using special characters as 'separators'?  Why not use a different schema that actually works and doesn't use special characters?

Comment: @J_A_X I know. This is a legacy code I am not responsible for and will  likely not change (as the change would break existing URLs). So the new angular app just need to use these URLs :)

Comment: @PetrPeller Gotcha.  Hope you get to fix the core of it eventually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS: avoid url encoding with $location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225980/angularjs-avoid-url-encoding-with-location)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that .search() uses encodeUriQuery that internally uses encodeURIComponent and [this function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) escapes all characters except the following: alphabetic, decimal digits, - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )

The current function inside Angular's [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/834d316829afdd0cc6a680f47d4c9b691edcc989/src/Angular.js#L1090):

```
/**
 * This method is intended for encoding *key* or *value* parts of query component. We need a custom
 * method because encodeURIComponent is too aggressive and encodes stuff that doesn't have to be
 * encoded per http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986:
 *    query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
 *    pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
 *    unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
 *    pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
 *    sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
 *                     / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
 */
function encodeUriQuery(val, pctEncodeSpaces) {
  return encodeURIComponent(val).
             replace(/%40/gi, '@').
             replace(/%3A/gi, ':').
             replace(/%24/g, '$').
             replace(/%2C/gi, ',').
             replace(/%20/g, (pctEncodeSpaces ? '%20' : '+'));
}
```

If that function had this additional replaces, then the brackets will keep unencoded:

```
replace(/%5B/gi, '[').
replace(/%5D/gi, ']').
```